# Do not delete a certain folder from server when Publishing using msbuild with SkipExtraFilesOnServer set to false

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I deploy an application to the server using Msbuild with `/p:WebPublishMethod=MSDeploy` and a switch to delete extra files on server  `/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=false`.

But there is an additional folder that I do not want to be deleted and/or altered in any way during publishing.

In one of my other projects I use `msdeploy` with the following switch
`-skip:Directory=\\dir` and it does exactly what I need.

I could not figure out how to pass the skip:directory parameter from **msbuild** to **msdeploy**. I tried different versions of `/p:` parameter but did not manage to get the right one.

Any thougts?

Comment: In that case, why don't you just chain the two commands and passin the parameter to the msdeploy instead?

Comment: @ZhaoHainan I did not quite understand what you mean. Can you give me an example?